# Metro has encountered an error: while trying to resolve module "idb-keyval' from file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, back4app

Trying to connect to a database (back4app) in React Native following this doc: https://www.back4app.com/docs/react-native/parse-sdk/react-native-sdk
I was given this error message:

While trying to resolve module `idb-keyval` from file `/Users/chenhana/TestRegistration/node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/IndexedDBStorageController.js`, the package `/Users/chenhana/TestRegistration/node_modules/idb-keyval/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/chenhana/TestRegistration/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /Users/chenhana/TestRegistration/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- /Users/chenhana/TestRegistration/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)

Tried resetting cache, deleting and reinstalling npm modules, and followed along with the doc (also installed the Parse Javascript SDK) so I'm not too sure why this error keeps coming up. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `metro.conf.js` file, put the following code:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");
module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

It might solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your `metro.config.js` for this:

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
const defaultSourceExts =
  require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults').sourceExts;
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT
      ? [...process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',').concat(defaultSourceExts), 'cjs'] // <-- cjs added here
      : [...defaultSourceExts, 'cjs'], // <-- cjs added here
  },
};
```